# Should I override the Object.equals(Object) method?

Tags: java, equals, equality, object-comparison

I have two instances of the same class.

```
public class Gilda {
    private String nome;
    public Gilda(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    // More stuff
}
```

When trying to compare them via `Object.equals(Object)` method, it returns `false`.
This is strange because `nome` has the same value on both of these instances.

How does the comparison work? Is this the expected behavior?
Should I override that method?

Comment: It depends whether you want to compare by reference or by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to override it. By not doing that, you are using the version that `Object` itself provides, which defaults to reference equality (they are the same "physical" object).

Depending on your IDE, this could be written automatically for you. For instance, IntelliJ 14 just wrote this for me:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Gilda gilda = (Gilda) o;
    if (nome != null ? !nome.equals(gilda.nome) : gilda.nome != null) return false;

    return true;
}
```

And of course, don't forget `hashCode`, which should always be done at the same time as `equals`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return nome != null ? nome.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do we cast to a `Gilda` instance for the `Object.equals(Object)` method but we use the `nome` variable for the `Object.hashCode()` one?

Comment: Because with `equals` you are comparing a Gilda (this) to some other kind of object, of any type. However, in `hashCode`, you are saying "give me this exact object's hash code". And since `nome` is the only aspect to that object, we're just delegating the work to the `String` represented by `nome`.

Comment: What if I have any other variables or methods?

Comment: Then you would have to account for them if they have any bearing on equality or hashing. Again, most IDEs would do this for you, it's a rare day when I have to hand code one of these methods any more.

Comment: `nome` is declared as `private`, but I can access it. Why?

Comment: Because when something is private, it is only visible to objects of that type. So any `Gilda` object can read the private instance fields or call private methods on any other `Gilda` object. It's not limited to the object instance that field is on.

Answer (score 0):

You must override the equals method - and accordingly - you must override  hashCode with it.